# How to crawl only specific specific tags and text in page? Python Scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

**Hello everyone!**

**How do i crawl only quotes that have the tag "Life", for example?**

**And how do i crawl only quotes that have an specific word on its text?**
I probably should use the scrapy rules for that, but i don`t know how..

```
class QuotesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/login',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        token = response.css('form input::attr(value)').extract_first()
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={
            'csrf_token' : token,
            'username' : 'test@test.com',
            'password' : 'test'
        }, callback=self.scrap_content)

    def scrap_content(self, response):
        #open_in_browser(response) Apenas para testar se o login funcionou.

        items = testItem()
        
        quotes_div = response.css('div.quote')
        
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        
        for quote in quotes_div:
            text = quote.css('span.text::text').extract()
            author = quote.css('.author::text').extract()
            tag = quote.css('.tag::text').extract()
            
            items['text'] = text
            items['author'] = author
            items['tag'] = tag
            items['page'] = page
            yield items
            
        next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback= self.scrap_content)
```

Answer (score 1):

To filter the tags create a list of tag or tags then if condition through get the desire output.

```
class QuotesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/login',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        token = response.css('form input::attr(value)').extract_first()
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={
            'csrf_token' : token,
            'username' : 'test@test.com',
            'password' : 'test'
        }, callback=self.scrap_content)

    def scrap_content(self, response):
        #open_in_browser(response) Apenas para testar se o login funcionou.

        items = {}

        quotes_div = response.css('div.quote')


        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]

        tags = ['misattributed-to-einstein']

        for quote in quotes_div:
            if quote.css('.tag::text').get() in tags:
                text = quote.css('span.text::text').extract()
                author = quote.css('.author::text').extract()
                tag = quote.css('.tag::text').extract()

                items['text'] = text
                items['author'] = author
                items['tag'] = tag
                items['page'] = page
                yield items

            next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').get()
            if next_page:
                yield response.follow(next_page, callback= self.scrap_content)
```